# Should heading tags be nested inside section tags?

Tags: html

Is this the correct approach?

```html
<section>
         <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
         <p>In this chapter we will....</p>
</section>
```

Or is this?

```html
<h2>Chapter 1</h2>
<section>
    <p>In this chapter we will....</p>
</section>
```

Comment: According to the [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element), "Each section should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1-h6 element)as a child of the section element."

Comment: Nice.  I like that succinct authoritative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section

In these examples, they use:

```
<article>
 <hgroup>
  <h1>Apples</h1>
  <h2>Tasty, delicious fruit!</h2>
 </hgroup>
 <p>The apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree.</p>
 <section>
  <h1>Red Delicious</h1>
  <p>These bright red apples are the most common found in many
  supermarkets.</p>
 </section>
 <section>
  <h1>Granny Smith</h1>
  <p>These juicy, green apples make a great filling for
  apple pies.</p>
 </section>
</article>
```

Suggesting an organization such as: `article` > `section` > `h1 + p`. I consider this an appropriate approach.

Quoting [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html):

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content. The theme of each section should be identified, typically by
>   including a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the section element.

Answer (score 0):

A `section`, like an `article` is like putting everything inside of it below the outer heading. As a demonstration, say you have this.

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h6>Small Heading</h6>
<section>
    <h1>Section Heading</h1>
</section>
```

The outline for this document is actually:

- Heading

  - Small Heading

    - Section Heading

Even though it's an `h1` below an `h6`, the `section` begins a subdocument.

The article at http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/ says:

> note that the heading goes inside the section element, not immediately before it

So, your first example is probably correct.